# how to find the installing path of some install application?

Tags: command-line, lubuntu, visual-studio-code

1. I install (using the terminal setup command) Visual Studio Code. 
   I can run it (by clicking on the icon on the 'all programs')  but I can't find the installation path of it.

I want to run it using `sudo` and I need to navigate to the installation path to use the terminal and call `sudo visualStudioCode` and I can't find it. (Try to use the 'find', but I can't find it.)

2. How can I create a shortcut of this `sudo visualStudioCode` on the Ubuntu desktop?

Comment: Which exact command did you use to install it? Do you know the name of the executable?

Comment: i not sure because it was 2-3 month ago - but maybe this 


sudo dpkg -i <file>.deb
sudo apt-get install -f # Install dependencies

Comment: It should be `vscode` and it doesn't require sudo.

Comment: but there is some python script that i want to debug and its need to have sudo to debug it

Comment: and call from the terminal 'sudo vscode ' does not find the vscode

Comment: quick hint(s):  to see what commands you entered, look at `history`  (which can be made to record date & time too).   also if you know the command that runs a program/app, use the `whereis sudo` to find out where the command sudo is stored by example...

Comment: @Yanshof run `sudo updatedb` then `locate -i visual | grep -i -e studio -e code` let me know what is the out put. also let me know about the output of `locate -i visual | grep -i desktop`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I tried

```
which code
```

, it returned 
/usr/bin/code

and to run, just typed

```
code
```

and it opened VS Code.
hope this helps

Comment: thank you so much @joy-grewal

Comment: Who the hell names their code editor's binary as "code"? I swear to f-cking god, I've been trying to find an executable starting with V forever. The audacity of calling your software "code"... This is like making a desktop manager application and calling the binaries "computer". Yes, I'm f-cking mad. (Thanks by the way)

Answer (score 0):

The binary for anything that you install using `apt-get dpkg` is usually either in /bin or /usr/bin directories from where you can run the program. You can also try to use the `which` command to locate pathnames of files which would be executed. So in your case, on a terminal, type:

```
which visualStudioCode
```

Comment: which visualStudioCode ... do nothing :(  and on the /bin and /usr/bin its not exist :(:(

Comment: I think then as per the comments above from wjandrea you would need to know the name of the executable. You could try searching using a regular expression with find to search for an approximate word or phrase.